Finding the amplitudes of a unentangled qubit in a pure quantum state
I'm working with a quantum state of $n$ qubits, represented as:
$$c_1|s_1\rangle_n + \cdots + c_k|s_k\rangle_n$$
where I know all the amplitudes $c_i$. Additionally, I know that the $j$-th qubit in this state is not entangled with the rest of the system.
Is there a procedure or method that allows me to isolate and calculate the amplitudes ($\alpha$ and $\beta$) of this specific $j$-th qubit, given that it's not entangled?

If the $j$th qubit is not entangled then you can throw away the others and your question reverts to to your previously asked question, doesn’t it?

Notation
Suppose$^1$ $k=2m$ and split the $k$ amplitudes $c_1,\ldots,c_{2m}$ into $a_1,\ldots,a_m$, for which the corresponding bit strings $s_i$ have a zero in the $j$th position, and $b_1,\ldots,b_m$, for which the corresponding bit strings $s_i$ have a one at the $j$th position. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}^{2^{n-1}}$ denote the vectors$^2$ of $a_i$ and $b_i$, respectively, where indexing is arranged so that $a_i$ and $b_i$ are amplitudes of $n$-bit strings that differ in exactly one position. The two vectors are not necessarily normalized and we don't interpret them as quantum states. They're a notational convenience.
Analysis
Tracing out all qubits except qubit $j$ from our $n$-qubit state yields the density matrix
\begin{align}
\rho=\begin{bmatrix}
\langle a,a\rangle & \langle b,a\rangle \\
\langle a,b\rangle & \langle b,b\rangle
\end{bmatrix}\tag1
\end{align}
Our task is then to find two complex numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle a,a\rangle & \langle b,a\rangle \\
\langle a,b\rangle & \langle b,b\rangle
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha\overline{\alpha} & \alpha\overline{\beta} \\
\beta\overline{\alpha} & \beta\overline{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}\tag2
\end{align}
Algorithm
If $\|a\|=0$, then $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$ is a solution$^3$ of $(2)$. Otherwise we're free to assume that $\alpha$ is a positive real number, so
\begin{align}
\alpha:=\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle} \quad\quad\quad
\beta:=\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}}\tag3
\end{align}
is a solution of $(2)$.
Note that the assignments in $(3)$ always satisfy the three scalar equations in $(2)$ that involve $\alpha$. The assignments satisfy $|\beta|=\langle b,b\rangle$ if and only if $\rho$ is rank one. This allows us to verify the promise that the $j$th qubit is unentangled with the rest.

$^1$ If none of the amplitudes $c_i$ is zero and the $j$th qubit is not entangled with the others, then $k$ is even.
$^2$ If $k < 2^n$, then this step involves padding with zeros.
$^3$ This follows from $\mathrm{tr}\rho=\langle a,a\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle=1$.


Could you explain me why we are free to assume that $\alpha$ is a real positive value, please?

Because the global phase doesn't matter. More precisely, in quantum mechanics $|\psi\rangle$ and $e^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle$ represent the same physical state for any $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Consequently, we are free to choose $\theta$ that renders any particular phase (e.g. that on $|0\rangle$) a positive real number (as long as the corresponding amplitude is non-zero of course).

Here is a simple Qiskit code to do that:
swap_circ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
swap_circ.swap(0, index)

psi = Statevector(amplitudes)
psi = psi.evolve(swap_circ)
state = psi.reset(range(1, num_qubits))
print(state.data[0:2])

Where amplitudes is the list of amplitudes, num_qubits is the number of qubits, and index is the separable qubit zero-based index.
